# Computing Point Spectrum and Resolvent of Multiplication Operator on [0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Not Homework - Just Personal Study

I have (hopefully) solved the problem I am posting, I would like to know if my proof is correct, and if not, what mistake did I make.

Consider $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. Define

$$
a(t)=\begin{cases}
2t & if \;\;0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & if \;\;\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Consider $T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ defined $T(f)(t)=a(t)f(t).$ I want to find the point spectrum (eigenvalues) and resolvent set for $T.$

For the eigenvalues, we proceed by cases noting that $T(f)=\lambda f$ if and only if  $(a(t)-\lambda)f(t)=0.$

For the case of $t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ we have $(2t-\lambda)f(t)=0$ which implies $\lambda=2t, 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}.$ So for this case the eigenvalues are all $\lambda \in [0,1].$

For the case of $\lambda=1$ we have by an identical argument that the only eigenvalue is 1. Thus the point spectrum is $[0,1]\cap\{1\}=\{1\}$

For the resolvent set we again have two cases. For $t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ we have

$$(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(f)=\frac{f(t)}{2t-\lambda}$$

and for $t \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$ we have

$$(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(f)=\frac{f(t)}{1-\lambda}$$

In the first case, $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$  exists and is bounded for $2t \neq \lambda$ so that $\lambda \notin [0,1]$

In the second case, $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded for $\lambda \neq 1.$ Thus the resolvent set is $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]. \qed$

Comment: Your argument for the eigenvalues does not seem stringent to me (while the result is correct).  To show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue you need to find nonzero $f$ that satisfies  $(a(t) - \lambda) f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. So you can show that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue by showing that if it was, then the above equation implies $f=0$. And to show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue you need to construct a nonzero $f$ that satisfies the above equation.

Comment: Your argument for the resolvent doesnt make much sense either. You cant separate the cases like that. You need to find one bounded operator that is inverse to $T- \lambda I$.

Comment: @jd27 Thank you for the feedback, it was very helpful. I feel like I have correctly shown that the only possible eigenvalue is 1. So to show that it is in fact an eigenvalue, I need to produce non-zero f such that a(t)f(t)=f(t). This would require the equations 2tf(t)=f(t) to be satisfied because for a(t)=1, any f will work. Could you help with finding such an $f$? Also, I do not see why I cannot separate cases like that  for the inverse. The original function is piece-wise defined, so I found the pieces wise inverse which is itself bounded.

Comment: Any continuous function, which vanishes on $[0,1/2]$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1.$ Concerning the resolvent of the operator $(Tf)(x)=a(x)f(x)$ for a continuous function $a$ the resolvent is given by $[(\lambda I-T)^{-1}f ](x)={f(x)\over \lambda -a(x)},$ where $\lambda$ does not belong to the range of the function $a.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I forgot that in math, if you have a problem, a good strategy is to try and make it go away. Thank you for the helpful hint, I now feel I have a complete proof that the point spectrum is just the singleton set 1. Thank you for your time and help !!!! For the second half of the comment, I feel like this is exactly what I did computationally, so I am not sure where my argument for the resolvent breaks down.